# Mongoose not connecting on production site

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When I use mongoose on my laptop with localhost, it doesn't show any errors with connecting to the database but when I move the app to the production URL, it returns a {}. Please what could be the cause of the error and the best possible fix? I'm already getting frustrated as it is.

Here's a bit of my code:

```
const   express = require ('express'),
        mongoose = require ("mongoose"),
        Model = require("././models/model"),
        bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
        app = express();

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.static("public"));
require('dotenv').config({ path: './.env'});
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

//ROUTES
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render("index")
})
app.post('/', function(req, res){
    var main= new Model({
        from: req.body.from,
        to: req.body.to,
        amount: req.body.amount,
        description: req.body.description
    })
    main.save(function(err, mainModel){
        if (err){
            res.send(err)
        }else{
            res.redirect('/')
            
        }
    })
})


mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, function(){
    console.log("APP IS RUNNING!!!")
})
```

P.S: Everything works on my laptop and the post request redirects to '/' but on the production URL, the post request is not completed and it redirects to an empty page with just {}. I'm using a live DB for process.env.DATABASEURL

Comment: This sounds like your `DATABASE_URL` is wrong, or your server isn't allowed to connect to it. There probably is an error message to tell you what is going wrong. See the docs on how to view the error: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#error-handling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I had VPN turned on while trying to access the database from my application. I turned off my VPN and everything was working perfectly.